# The type of one of the expressions in the group by clause is incorrect

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```cs
public object GetGenelStok(NetSatisContext context , string stokKodu)
var result = (from c in context.StokHareketleri.Where(c => c.StokKodu == stokKodu)
              group c by new(c.Hareket)
              into g
              select new
              {
                  Bilgi = g.Key.Hareket,
                  KayitSayisi = g.Count(),
                  Toplam=g.Sum(c=>c.Miktar)

              }).ToList();

            return result;
```

That is my code firstly I took the C# should be greater than 7.2 error after I fixed that error I take the "The type of one of the expressions in the group by clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupBy'" error

Comment: From : g.Key.Hareket To : g.Key

Comment: What do you expect `new(c.Hareket)` to do? It looks like you're expecting type interference to guess what your group key type should be, but it won't be able to. Just specify the type explicitly, assuming you want to create a new instance of *something*.

Comment: If you only want `Harekey` as the key, then change `new(c.Hareket)` to just `c.Hareket`, and then `g.Key.Hareket` to `g.Key`

Comment: I need the new(c.Hareket) because it means for movement of stock so in every time it should change for different stocks